# What happens when you 'or' two mismatched Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

So, I created two series of 100 elements and 'or'd them together.
But first I 'sorted' the first series, meaning that the indexes don't line up.
I expected an error. Or bad results. But what I got was a third series with 126 elements! That was a surprise. Any ideas why?

Please notice the 4 rows of "Richardson" in the billy_or_peter output listing. There are 4 values, two are 'True' and two are 'False'.

I thought there might be some sort of 'cartesian product' resulting in 200 rows. But instead, I see 126 rows - which is very strange.

Thoughts?

```py
# Loc and Iloc also allow for conditional statments to filter rows of data
# using Loc on the logic test above only returns rows where the result is True
only_billys = df.loc[df["first_name"] == "Billy", :]
print(only_billys)

only_peters = df.loc[df["first_name"] == "Peter", :]
print(only_peters)
print()

only_richardsons = df.loc["Richardson", :]
print(only_richardsons)
print()

isBilly = (df["first_name"] == "Billy").sort_index()
print(isBilly.describe())
print()

isPeter = (df["first_name"] == "Peter")
print(isPeter.describe())
print()

billy_or_peter = isPeter | isBilly
print(billy_or_peter.describe())
print(billy_or_peter)
```

OUTPUT

```
(only_billys)
           id first_name      Phone Number       Time zone
last_name                                                 
Clark      20      Billy  62-(213)345-2549   Asia/Makassar
Andrews    23      Billy  86-(859)746-5367  Asia/Chongqing
Price      59      Billy  86-(878)547-7739   Asia/Shanghai
            id first_name     Phone Number      Time zone

(only_peters)
last_name                                                
Richardson   1      Peter  7-(789)867-9023  Europe/Moscow

            id first_name      Phone Number      Time zone

(only_richardsons)
last_name                                                 
Richardson   1      Peter   7-(789)867-9023  Europe/Moscow
Richardson  25     Donald  62-(259)282-5871   Asia/Jakarta

(isBilly.describe() - sorted index)
count       100
unique        2
top       False
freq         97
Name: first_name, dtype: object

(isPeter.describe())
count       100
unique        2
top       False
freq         99
Name: first_name, dtype: object

(billy_or_peter.describe() - 126 rows???)
count       126
unique        2
top       False
freq        121
Name: first_name, dtype: object

(billy_or_peter listing - notice 4 Richardsons where before there were only 2)
last_name
Adams         False
Allen         False
Andrews        True
Austin        False
Baker         False
Banks         False
Bell          False
Berry         False
Bishop        False
Black         False
Brooks        False
Brown         False
Bryant        False
Bryant        False
Bryant        False
Bryant        False
Burke         False
Butler        False
Butler        False
Butler        False
Butler        False
Carroll       False
Chapman       False
Chavez        False
Clark          True
Collins       False
Cook          False
Day           False
Day           False
Day           False
              ...  
Price          True
Reid          False
Reyes         False
Rice          False
*Richardson     True
*Richardson     True
*Richardson    False
*Richardson    False
Riley         False
Roberts       False
Robertson     False
Robinson      False
Rogers        False
Scott         False
Shaw          False
Shaw          False
Shaw          False
Shaw          False
Simmons       False
Snyder        False
Sullivan      False
Torres        False
Tucker        False
Vasquez       False
Wagner        False
Walker        False
Washington    False
Watkins       False
Wells         False
Williamson    False
Name: first_name, Length: 126, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mismatching isn't the problem here, `pandas` will align before the `|`. Your issue is due to a duplicated index. For that, the comparison is done as an `outer` join within matching Indices. Thus, 2 Richardsons in one and 2 Richardsons in another will lead to 4 rows in your output.

To illustrate this point more clearly, look at what happens when adding strings with duplicated and misaligned indices. We get 6 (2 x 3) rows for Index 1, from the cartesian product:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list('abcd'), index=[1,1,2,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list('1243'), index=[1,1,3,1])
df1+df2

     0
1   a1
1   a2
1   a3
1   b1
1   b2
1   b3
2  NaN
3   d4
```

Comment: Many thanks. I'm new to Pandas and this was a surprise. Now... it all makes perfect sense.